# Selenoid not finding chrome image

Tags: docker, selenium, selenoid, selenium-hub

Browsers.json file

```
{
    "chrome": {
        "default": "latest",
        "versions": {
            "latest": {
                "image": "selenoid/chrome:latest",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Docker image ls

```
REPOSITORY             TAG              IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
selenoid/chrome        latest           6c08b8cfe30e   3 weeks ago    1.14GB
aerokube/selenoid      latest           fdc2ce7d1eb8   3 months ago   16.2MB
```

Docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  selenoid:
    image: "aerokube/selenoid"
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4000:4444"
    volumes:
      - ".:/etc/selenoid/" # assumed current dir contains browsers.json
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    command: ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json","-log-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/logs"]
http://localhost:8086/status
{"state":{"total":5,"used":0,"queued":0,"pending":0,"browsers":{"MicrosoftEdge":{"latest":{}},"chrome":{"latest":{}},"firefox":{"latest":{}}},"videos":null},"origin":"http://selenoid:4444","browsers":{"MicrosoftEdge":0,"chrome":0,"firefox":0},"sessions":{},"version":"1.10.4[2021-10-10_08:53:47AM]","errors":[]}
```

I am running this using docker vm created by lima. When I run the tests it says the below error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: create container: Error response from daemon: No such image: selenoid/chrome:latest
```

Even though I have selenoid/chrome:latest, selenoid is not able to connect to it and throws not found error. But it works with docker desktop. What config , I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom docker network. Like this:

```
networks:
  app:
    external:
      name: app
```

Network should be already exist
You can do it via command

```
docker network create app
```

After that add this network to your service:

```
networks:
  app: null
```

For more information use this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_option_2_running_selenoid_in_custom_docker_network)